# Class not found with Struts2 and Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, struts2, libraries, classnotfoundexception

I'm using Netbeans 7.1, and i try to include Struts2.3.14.3 in my J2EE project.

I tried to :

- put the .jars in the WEB-INF/lib path
- link the .jars in the libraries "folder" of the project in Netbeans
- create a librarie including the .jars and link it to the project

But none of these solutions work, when i deploy the application on my Glassfish server it keeps rising these kind of error :

```
Grave: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/xxx/dist/gfdeploy/xxx/lib/struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.14.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:32:155
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:473)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5377)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:219)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:253)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:145)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishDecorator.start(GlassFishDecorator.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishImpl.start(OSGiGlassFishImpl.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.convention.ActionConfigBuilder class:org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder - bean - jar:file:/C:/xxx/dist/gfdeploy/xxx/lib/struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.14.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:32:155
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:226)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts2/StrutsException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1853)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:235)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.StrutsException
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:787)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:696)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 47 more
```

I have verified manually, and org.apache.struts2.StrutsException is present in the strut2-core.jar.

Here the jars i use:

```
asm-3.3
asm-common-3.3
asm-tree-3.3
commons-fileupload-1.2.2
commons-io-2.0.1
commons-lang-2.4
commons-lang3-3.1
freemarket-2.3.19
javassist-3.11.0.GA
ongl-3.0.6
struts2-conventin-plugin-2.3.14.3
xwork-core-2.3.14.3
struts2-bootstrap-plugin-1.6.1
struts2-core-2.3.14.3
```

Comment: `freemarkeT` ? `convenTIN` ? Are they *sweded version* of the official libraries ? Beware of the imitations... :D

Answer (score 0):

You need a structure *like* this:

> - YourEar.ear
>
>   - lib
>
>     - library1.jar
>     - library2.jar
>     - libraryN.jar
>   - META-INF
>   - YourWar.war
>
>     - jsp
>
>       - jsp1.jsp
>       - jsp2.jsp
>       - jspN.jsp
>     - META-INF
>     - WEB-INF
>
>       - lib
>
>         - libraryA.jar
>         - libraryB.jar
>         - libraryX.jar
>       - classes
>
>         - your.package.your.classes.etc...
>         - struts.xml
>       - web.xml

Struts libraries goes inside war, not ear (libraryA, B, X...)

Open the generated ear/war and check thet everything is on its right place.